# Can I set up a VPN server on my home network?

Tags: networking, vpn, openvpn

I do not completely understand how VPN's work so I was wondering that if I set up a VPN server on my local network (say, using a raspberry pi and openvpn), and access said server from the same network, can my ISP see all my traffic?

To my understanding, a VPN server needs to be on a foreign network for your ISP to not be able to see your traffic. Am I right or am I missing something?

Also, incase I am right, and it does need to be on a foreign network, is there any way I can have the VPN server on my local network without my ISP looking at my traffic?

Thank you.

Comment: Have a read of https://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2017/05/how-to-build-your-own-vpn-if-youre-rightfully-wary-of-commercial-options/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can technically set up a VPN server on your home network provided that you either have a static IP address or a mechanism to find it from the wider Internet (Dynamic DNS is often used)

A VPN server encrypts traffic across the link - however it is visible on the remote side of the link - thus if you use the same ISP, and they choose to sniff the data they will be able to see it - and worse, they will probably be able to cross-correlate it with traffic across the VPN based on size and timing if they really want to.

A VPN really only provides encryption between its points - so its good if you want to - for example - connect to an office and ensure the data is private.
It can also be used to obfusicate your location - the traffic will appear to originate on the remote side of the VPN, and from that IP - which means your local ISP won't see it, and you appear to come from somewhere else.  Exactly how good this protection is comes down to the logs, policies and credibility of your VPN provider.

Your question is a bit unclear, but if you want to communicate from work with your machine at home - a VPN is a good idea and will protect you from your ISP.  They will be able to see you are communicating with your home network, but not what you are doing.

Comment: Apologies for the unclear question. Your second paragraph answered my question though. Thanks!